# How to force Save link as, download link, to not ignore the active service worker?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, download, service-worker

I have a web page with an active service-worker. The page has links with `<a>` and when clicked the request is intercepted by the service worker as expected. However, when the user right clicks the link and chooses save as ... then the service worker is ignored ( and a normal request is send to the server as if there was no service worker) .

How can one force the **save as** functionality to go through the service worker ?

Answer should rely on changing links to buttons or changing the non service worker client part.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `href` to `javascript:void(0)`, use `data-*` attribute to store URL which should be fetched, at `click` of `<a>` element use `fetch()`, which should make request that `ServiceWorker` can intercept.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" 
  data-href="placehold.it/1x1" 
  title="placehold.it">placehold.it</a>
<script>
  document.querySelector("a").onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var request = fetch(location.protocol + "//" + this.dataset.href);
    request.then(response => response.blob())
    .then(blob => console.log(blob))
  }
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The save link as ... is not shown in your example. I need the save link as to be there.

Comment: @WalleCyril Do you mean using `download` attribute?

Comment: I mean the save link as option in the popout menu when you right click (or touch long in touchscreen)

Comment: @WalleCyril Have not found selecting `Save link as...` makes an additional request for the resource. Can you create a plnkr to demonstrate what you are trying to achieve?