# How can "Save Link As" be made to use service worker?

Tags: browser, service-worker

My web page has some hrefs to documents where the server side checks to make sure the user has included an Authorization header. This header is added to the request by a service worker, and it works fine if the user clicks on the link, or right-clicks and picks "Open Link in New Tab," but not when they right-click and pick "Save Link As..." In that last case I can see from the browser dev tools that the service worker code that adds the auth header is not being run. I've tried Firefox and Chrome. I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40519266/how-to-force-save-link-as-download-link-to-not-ignore-the-active-service-worke), but it has no solution.

If a service worker is installed shouldn't all requests go through it? How can I get "Save Link As..." to run through my service worker? I suppose I could experiment with a "Download" button or something on the page next to each link, and expect the user to never try "Save Link As...," but I really want anchors with simple hrefs where the standard browser mechanisms all work.